# Can every well ordered chain be reduced to a countable chain?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

Let $X$ be a set, $I$ a well ordered set and $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ a family of subsets of $X$ such that

$$X_i\subseteq X_j\mbox{ for }i\leq j$$
$$\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i=X$$

Does there always exist a countable sequence of indexes $(i_n)\subset I$ such that

$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_{i_n}=X$$
?

Comment: Just mentionning this: if $I$ is any linearly ordered set, then the union can be replaced by the union of a family indexed by the cofinality of $I$, and no lesser ordinal will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO. Not if you have the axiom of choice. For example when $X=I$ and $X$ is an uncountable regular cardinal, ordered by $\in.$

Comment: As pointed out by Max in his A,  it suffices that cf(X) be uncountable.

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't, most of the time.

For instance assume $X$ is a(n uncountable) cardinal with uncountable cofinality, for instance $\omega_1, \aleph_{\omega_1},...$ (and many many others), then the family $(\alpha)_{\alpha < X}$ is a well-ordered family satisfying the conditions you gave, but there is no such countable subfamily, by definition of cofinality

Comment: One should note that it is consistent without choice that all well-ordered sets have countable cofinality.

Comment: Indeed, but not with countable choice if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes. Countable choice suffices to prove that successor cardinals are always of uncountable cofinality.